# How to change the name of the output in matlab function to other than ans

Tags: matlab

I am new to Matlab and the answer may be very simple. I have script that runs a function to return an answer matrix, ans. How can I get Matlab to return a matrix named J instead?

Here is how I call the function: (myfunction(a,b));

I get the following error if i try to call 'myfunction = J'.

Error using myfunction (line 10)
Not enough input arguments.

Error in myfunction (line 25)
J = myfunction

If remove the line myfunction = J. I no longer get an error in line 10 any more.

Thanks

The problem was I was trying to name the output in the function where as I should have defined this in my script.

SO instead of calling the function as:

(myfunction(a,b));

Instead it should be: J=(myfunction(a,b));

Comment: use the name with `=` sign to assign to a new variable.  `J=f(...)`

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you call your script.

If you do:

```
> myScript;
```

in the command window, the result will be stored in the variable `ans`.

If you do:

```
> J = myScript;
```

The result will be stored in `J`.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever function you have it should have at least one output in your case (because you say that you expect something). So for instance if your function returns one variable write it as

[T]=myfunction(a,b);

so in this case T is the name of your output instead of "ans". You need to write your function in a separate .m file and save it under the same name as is the name of function, so in this case you need to save it as myfunction.m file. It has to be in the same folder as your main code is.
See the link below

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html